# How to read EXCEL files in for-loop with python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am a beginner of Python.
Now, I have files "Pref1" and "Pref2".
I would like to read files and define data frame's names with for-loop fuction (there are so many files).
I tried below.

```
for i in [1,2]:
    f"df{i} = pd.read_excel('Pref{i}.xlsx', sheet_name= 'Sheet2').dropna(axis=0)
```

However, codes do not work.
If you have good ideas, please tell me. Thank you.

Comment: for i in range(1,2):

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary to save your data frames with preferred names and get them later

**CODE**

```
import pandas as pd

df_dict = {}

for i in [1, 2]:
    df_dict["df"+str(i)] = pd.read_excel(f'Pref{i}.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet2').dropna(axis=0)

df1 = df_dict["df1"]
df2 = df_dict["df2"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! The code works!!
But is it difficult to save data and name at once?

Comment: A dictionary or List is the only way for achieving this